# Why are all cookies with same name included when asked by server? Doesn't it raise cookie's integrity violation chances?

Tags: web-browser, http, cookies

Cookies are set and stored as a name/domain/path to value attributes mapping, but only name-value pairs are presented to both JavaScript and web servers. This asymmetry allows cookies with the same name but different domain and/or path scopes to be written into browser; a subsequent reader can read out all same name cookies together, yet cannot distinguish them because the other attributes such as path are not presented in the reading process.

Comment: Integrity would only be at risk if you could write to a cookie you didn't own. You seem to be talking about reading cookies, which is a confidentiality issue.

Comment: Do you have a source or example of this happening? When can a server read the cookies of another domain when they have the same cookie name?

Comment: @schroeder Sort of integrity issue because in case original cookie is overwritten by another one and that new cookie is included when server calls, rather than the original one.

Comment: Ok, then you need to include that detail in your question, because you only make the case for reading cookies.

Comment: What "subsequent readers" are you talking about?

Comment: @Anders I think he means the web servers that call for their cookie, but get all cookies with the same name. Hence my request for some kind of evidence that this is possible.

Comment: Just got a question while reading this post . If a server hosting multiple sites  and I am accessing them via ip address how will the browser

Comment: @Anders exactly, that subsequent user can be that web server

Answer (score 1):

The Same Origin Policy creates a security boundary for client-side data defined by protocol, port and domain.

The Same Origin Policy for cookies is slightly looser, allowing the protocol and port to differ, and the domain can optionally share cookies with subdomains. Note, as you say, this is optional for the cookie writer only, not the reader.

That is, `foo.example.com` can write a cookie that `example.com` can read, even if it doesn't want to.

The solution to this is to only have one application per domain. That way two applications cannot set cookies for each other.

### e.g. Vulnerable

Application running on `example.com/foo` which can set set cookies for `example.com/bar`

### Not Vulnerable

Application running on `foo.example.com` - this is completely isolated from `bar.example.org`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem.

Due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), client scripts (e.g. JavaScript) should only be able to read and write cookies belonging to the current domain. So for the client script interacting with the cookie, there is only one cookie per name - it should not even be aware of cookies for other domains. Therefore it does not need to specify what domain it is reading cookies from - it is always the current one.

Requiring that to be specified would be like your car key asking you what car you want to unlock every time you press the unlock button - obviously it is your car, the only car the key can unlock.

In a similar fashion, when the browser sends a request to `http://example.com` it only includes cookies for `example.com`, and no cookies belonging to other domains even if they have the same name as `example.com` cookies. A browser doing anything else would be a major malfunction and a critical security issue, but to my knowledge no major browser vendor has so far messed up that badly.

I do not know what kind of "subsequent readers" you are talking about. Only the browser is supposed to read the cookies, and it is the responsibility of the browser to enforce the SOP.

*(Subdomains makes this slightly more complicated, but I think that is beside the point of your question.)*

Comment: Just got a question while reading this post . If a server hosting multiple sites  and I am accessing them via ip address how will the browser select which cookie is for which as site. ?

Comment: @8zero2.ops I *think* the IP address is counted as a separate origin, so if you serve `example.com` from `127.0.0.1` the browser will not send cookies stored for `example.com` if you type in `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: No I mean how to distinguish cookies for a.a.a.a:80 and a.a.a.a:8080. If both are plain http sites .. I am browsing via my browser

Comment: @8zero2.ops Different ports mean different origin. Except for IE who does not always follow that, I think.

Comment: Ohk .. I will check it whether ports are accountable for storing different different cookies ..thank you